# Renaming all variables and literals without obfuscation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I want to rename all the classes and variables in my code to make it more obfuscated. For example, this sample code:

```
public class Dog
{
   public Dog()
   {
      Bark(4);
   }

   private void Bark(int times)
   {
       //Do something
   }
}
```

becomes:

```
public class Cat
{
   public Cat()
   {
      Wood(4);
   }

   private void Wood(int asdasd)
   {
       //Do something
   }
}
```

If this is not possible, perhaps something even simpler where we simply add a character to the middle of every variable/name:

```
public class Do1g
{
   public Do1g()
   {
      Bar1k(4);
   }

   private void Bar1k(int time1s)
   {
       //Do something
   }
}
```

The functionality stays the same, and it is human-readable; however, all information on variable namings, classes, methods, etc, are changed.

**Is there a way to obfuscate, while maintaining readability?**

Comment: What's your goal to rename things while keeping it working??? Just asking because that's not really _obfuscation_...

Comment: Should it create a new class with new variables or should it create a new object with the look of the desired(obfuscated) object?

Comment: @Neil either one would work

Comment: Looks like you want "refactoring", which is a built in feature in Visual Studio itself. Keyboard shortcut CTRL + R + R

Comment: @Rumplin that would be a very manual process because you would have to do it individually for every variable

Comment: I really don't see a reason why one would do this anyway :) you could write a macro in Notepad++ maybe.

Comment: Create a [T4 template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Part of "maintaining readability" means that objects are called what they mean. If I see a `Cat` class and it really means `Dog`, I'm going to get super confused and it's going to make my job as a programmer harder. The only time you should be doing any sort of obfuscation is when you are building your code and want to add a small layer of protection to your final binary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio Code Model to rename symbols. For example, to add 'x' to the current function name:

```
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    EnvDTE80.CodeElement2 func = ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction]
        as EnvDTE80.CodeElement2;
    func.RenameSymbol(func.Name + "x");
```

(You can run this code with Visual Commander or use in your own extension).

This rename operation also updates all references. You can naturally expand this sample to rename classes, namespaces and process files, projects.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I have no idea how this could ever be used but, in the comments you said that creating a new object that looks like the desired object is acceptable so

Here is my proposal

1. Read all the methods of the class using reflection
2. Create a List with all the properties's and methods's names from step 1

From there you can create a new object using LINQ with the names created from the list you created.

Keep in mind I don't know how or even if this would work.

Comment: By the way if this works please show how you did it. would be interesting to see

Comment: Well it seemed a but long to be a comment and thats what i would try so seems good enough to be an answer